# Can i use while loop with 'i' as a variable which will be used in tr[i] in xpath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

```
import scrapy
import logging

class AssetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'asset'
    start_urls = ['http://mnregaweb4.nic.in/netnrega/asset_report_dtl.aspx?lflag=eng&state_name=WEST%20BENGAL&state_code=32&district_name=NADIA&district_code=3201&block_name=KRISHNAGAR-I&block_code=&panchayat_name=DOGACHI&panchayat_code=3201009009&fin_year=2020-2021&source=national&Digest=8+kWKUdwzDQA1IJ5qhD8Fw']
def parse(self, response):
    i = 4
    while i<2236:
        assetid = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr['i']/td[2]/text()")
        assetcategory = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr['i']/td[3]/text()")
        schemecode = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr['i']/td[5]/text()")
        link = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr['i']/td[6]/a/@href")
        schemename = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr['i']/td[7]/text()")
        yield {
            'assetid' : assetid,
            'assetcategory' : assetcategory,
            'schemecode' : schemecode,
            'link' : link,
            'schemename' : schemename
        }
        i += 1
```

I want to use 'i' variable to loop in the xpath of tr[position] from 4 to 2235. i just dont know if it is possible! and if it is possible, then what is the right way to do it? mine does not work.

Comment: Use f-strings: `f"//table[2]//tr[{i}]/td[2]/text()"`.

Comment: _Can_ you? Yes. _Is it idiomatic, good practice_? Personally, I'd consider `for i in range(4, 2236):` to be far more readable. Mind, to actually use the value in your xpath, the f-string approach being suggested is appropriate if-and-when the xpath engine you're using doesn't support bind variables..

Comment: (XPath itself supports things like `.../tr[$i]/...`, with key/value dictionary passed in to describe what value `i` has; but whether scrapy's XPath implementation in particular supports that is an entirely different question, and I don't have an answer to it).

Comment: Turns out it _is_ possible in scrapy -- see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#variables-in-xpath-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is possible and widely used.
You can format the string with variable.
There are several syntaxes for that.
For example you can do it like this:

```
i = 4
while i<2236:
    assetid_path = "//table[2]//tr[{1}]/td[2]/text()".format(i)
    assetcategory_path = "//table[2]//tr[{1}]/td[3]/text()".format(i)
    schemecode_path = "//table[2]//tr[{1}]/td[5]/text()".format(i)
    link_path = "//table[2]//tr[{1}]/td[6]/a/@href".format(i)
    schemename_path = "//table[2]//tr[{1}]/td[7]/text()".format(i)
    assetid = response.xpath(assetid_path)
    assetcategory = response.xpath(assetcategory_path)
    schemecode = response.xpath(schemecode_path)
    link = response.xpath(link_path)
    schemename = response.xpath(schemename_path)
    yield {
        'assetid' : assetid,
        'assetcategory' : assetcategory,
        'schemecode' : schemecode,
        'link' : link,
        'schemename' : schemename
    }
    i += 1
```

While the above can be shortened like this:

```
i = 4
while i<2236:
    root_path = "//table[2]//tr[{1}]".format(i)
    assetid_path = root_path + "/td[2]/text()"
    assetcategory_path = root_path + "/td[3]/text()"
    schemecode_path = root_path + "/td[5]/text()"
    link_path = root_path + "/td[6]/a/@href"
    schemename_path = root_path + "/td[7]/text()"
    assetid = response.xpath(assetid_path)
    assetcategory = response.xpath(assetcategory_path)
    schemecode = response.xpath(schemecode_path)
    link = response.xpath(link_path)
    schemename = response.xpath(schemename_path)
    yield {
        'assetid' : assetid,
        'assetcategory' : assetcategory,
        'schemecode' : schemecode,
        'link' : link,
        'schemename' : schemename
    }
    i += 1
```

But the better way is to use bind variable. As following:

```
i = 4
while i<2236:
    assetid = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr[$i]/td[2]/text()",i=i))
    assetcategory = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr[$i]/td[3]/text()",i=i))
    schemecode = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr[$i]/td[5]/text()",i=i)
    link = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr[$i]/td[6]/a/@href",i=i)
    schemename = response.xpath("//table[2]//tr[$i]/td[7]/text()",i=i)
    yield {
        'assetid' : assetid,
        'assetcategory' : assetcategory,
        'schemecode' : schemecode,
        'link' : link,
        'schemename' : schemename
    }
    i += 1
```

Comment: Using bind variables should be preferred over using string substitution to generate queries, in XPath just as in SQL. Scrapy supports this; see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#variables-in-xpath-expressions

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Is now (the last approach) is what you wished to see? Is it correct?

Comment: By "the last approach", you mean the one using string formatting? No, it's not what I was aiming for. The approach described in the docs linked above would be like `response.xpath('//table[2]//tr[$i]/td[7]/text()', i=i)`

Comment: ...compare to the example in the link of `response.xpath('//div[count(a)=$cnt]/@id', cnt=5).get()`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see, thanks a lot. I'm not professional in Python. Now learnt some nice tip, thanks!

Comment: Using the variable is not just "better", if you're executing an expression 2200 times then any other way is thoroughly bad. Compiling the expression will probably cost 100 ms compared with 2ms for executing it, so by compiling it 2200 times you're wasting a vast amount of processing time.

Comment: Also, execute the common expression `//table[2]//tr[$i]` once to return the td node, then access the other nodes from this, either using relative path expressions or by direct DOM navigation.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, Michael. If you wish you are welcome to edit my answer accordingly to them.

Answer (score 0):

You send string to xpath so I would suggest to use formating... eg.:

```
 response.xpath(f"//table[2]//tr[{i}]/td[2]/text()")
```

Comment: Using bind variables should be preferred over using string substitution to generate queries, in XPath just as in SQL. Scrapy supports this; see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#variables-in-xpath-expressions -- particularly the `cnt=5` example, which is particularly on-point.